# Hibernate: mapping 3 tables

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I'm trying to map some existing tables with Hibernate.

It's quite simple: we've got categories that have names in multiple languages.

The DDL is as follows:

```
create table language (
   id                integer not null auto_increment,
   code              varchar(2) not null,

   unique (code),

   primary key(id)
);

create table category (
   id               integer not null auto_increment,
   parent_id        integer default null,
   ordr             integer not null default 99,

   primary key (id)
);

create table category_description (
   category_id      integer not null,
   language_id      integer not null,

   title            varchar(255) not null,

   constraint foreign key (category_id) references category(id),
   constraint foreign key (country_language_id) references country_language(id),

   primary key (category_id, country_language_id)
);
```

Now I'd like to have a map with Language as it's key and Description (table category_description) as it's value, like this:

```
private Map<Language, CategoryDescription> descriptions = new HashMap<Language, CategoryDescription>();
```

Can anyone provide me with some pointers on this? I've tried the example as given on page 311/312 from the 'Java Persistence with Hibernate' which resembles my problem but I'm just not getting it :(

Answer (score 2):

(Your DDL is inconsistent, you create a table "language" but reference a table "country_language" -- I will assume the latter)

Here is what the Hibernate mapping for your sample would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">

    <class name="Language" table="country_language">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="code" type="string" length="2" unique="true" />
    </class>

    <class name="Category" table="category">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <map name="descriptions" table="category_description">
            <key column="category_id" />
            <map-key-many-to-many column="language_id" class="Language" />
            <composite-element class="CategoryDescription">
                <property name="title" type="string" length="255" />
            </composite-element>
        </map>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, you don't need the `CategoryDescription` class at all (as it just wraps a `String`):

```
private Map<Language, String> descriptions;
```

and

```
<map name="descriptions" table="category_description">
    <key column="category_id" />
    <map-key-many-to-many column="language_id" class="Language" />
    <element type="string" length="255" column="title" />
</map>
```

would work just as well.

Note that in both cases your `Language` class would need to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` in order to be able to successfully query the resulting map:

```
/* eclipse generated */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* eclipse generated */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Language other = (Language) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi,

thanks a lot for the answer. We worked around it in a way I don't like but I will definitely try this out.

You're right about the DDL inconsistency; I tried to "simplify" things a bit but obviously missed something.

In that respect, the CategoryDescription was simplified as well, it has some more attributes.

We have the same 3-table setup for other entities as well (lots of our entities have multilingual descriptions which are designed in a similar way.

I'll post back as soon as I find the time to try your solution.

Thanks.